# Basic formatting of surfacelistbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

My surfacelistbox in my WPF c# app has a light coloured border around each item in the list. How can I get rid of this? Are there any padding properties etc. that can be changed that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Might be this?

```
<s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxBackgroundBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
```

From [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/a5a006b6-f0a5-43fb-aff8-1d840e8ea52b)

Comment: Nope, I've tried that - doesn't seem to affect the surfacelistbox at all. Also, I don't think it's just the background brush, it's the space that the background occupies - almost like padding. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Eben was almost right - but you need to change the ListBoxItem background color, not the ListBox:

```
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemBackgroundBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

If you want to hide the selected item background too, use:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemSelectionBackgroundBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```